# Puzzle returns unsupported TypeError

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python A*. I believe that my traversal and my heuristic are right but I get an error that I don't understand. I can't change the `main` test function but the rest can be manipulated.

The code for the puzzle is:

```
    def pop(self):
        pairs = list()
        for item in self.frontier:
            pairs.append((self.priority[item], item))
        (p, item) = min(pairs)
        self.frontier.remove(item)
        return item
```

The error that I get when I run the code reads:

```
125
487
36 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mchri/Desktop/AI/Homework/eightpuzzle/eightpuzzle.py", line 129, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/mchri/Desktop/AI/Homework/eightpuzzle/eightpuzzle.py", line 119, in main
    path = agent.astar(puzzle, goal)
  File "C:/Users/mchri/Desktop/AI/Homework/eightpuzzle/eightpuzzle.py", line 86, in astar
    parent = self.pop()
  File "C:/Users/mchri/Desktop/AI/Homework/eightpuzzle/eightpuzzle.py", line 106, in pop
    (p, item) = min(pairs)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Puzzle' and 'Puzzle'
```

The puzzle almost solves itself but begins to misplace the numbers and I don't understand how that's a result of the unsupported `<` instance.

Comment: in the future, please make a [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `min()` to get the lowest priority value out of a list of tuples, with priority values and puzzles. The way `min()` works, is that it compares both values in the tuple, so it will first sort by priority value, then by Puzzle. There is, however no `<` operator for Puzzle, because one puzzle is not less than the other.

I assume you just want to sort by priority value, which can be done like this:

`(p, item) = min(pairs, key=lambda t: t[0])`

If you do want to sort by both priority value and puzzle, you'll need to implement a `lt` an `eq` operator for Puzzle (See Brian Joseph's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Because, your code doesn't know which puzzle is "greater" than or "less" than the other. You need to define some -- if not all -- of these magic/dunder methods to tell python how to compare them:

```
__lt__(a, b)
__le__(a, b)
__eq__(a, b)  # <-- You already have this
__ne__(a, b)  # <-- You already have this
__ge__(a, b)
__gt__(a, b)
```

read more here: ["rich comparison" methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#richcmpfuncs).

Answer (score 0):

So I added a print statement, like so:

```
for item in self.frontier:
    pairs.append((self.priority[item], item))
print(pairs)  # <- My addition
(p, item) = min(pairs)
```

And your code fails when your `pairs` list looks like this:

```
[
    (10, <__main__.Puzzle object at 0x000002019C4C7278>),
    (10, <__main__.Puzzle object at 0x000002019C4C7358>),
    (12, <__main__.Puzzle object at 0x000002019C4C72B0>)
]
```

The way that `min` works on tuples is this: it compares the first item in each tuple. If those are *equal*, then it compares the next item. And so on and so forth until it finds an item pair that "breaks the tie", so to speak.

For the above `pairs` list, there are two tuples with a first element of `10`; since these are equal, the `min` function then tries to compare the two `Puzzle` objects. But `Puzzle` objects don't know how to be compared! So your code throws an error saying so.

But really, you just want to find the tuple with the smallest `p` value, right? So you can replace `(p, item) = min(pairs)` with this:

```
(p, item) = min(pairs, key=lambda t: t[0])
```